# How to use compile filetree in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to compile src_ext as libs just like I used in eclipse structrue.code is as follow

Code 1

[image: .]

Code 2

[image: .]

but it dosen't work anyway

Comment: Please do not use images. Provide all info as text.

Comment: You DO NOT want `*.java` files on your classpath. You want either `*.jar` or `*.class` files